# Javascript - How to get documents referrer with hash

Tags: javascript, iframe, hash

I wonder if this is possible. I was trying to access the referrer of the document inside an iframe but it always disregard the hash(#) value.

Root Page(index.html) - (`http://example.com/test#hashvalue`)

Inside the Root Page, there is an iframe that gets the referrer. It has this piece of code

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

This returns `http://example.com/test` without the hash value. Is there a way to get the full url(with hash) as a referrer.

**Note**: that I dont have access to Root page. If I do, I can use postMessage but I don't. The iframe was just embedded(Lets call it as a widget of the root page).

Comment: If the iframe and the main document are from different domains, then you don’t have any JS access to the location of the main document, because of the Same Origin Policy. In that case, `document.referrer` is all you get. And if that doesn’t include the hash part, then you’re out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Any url that contains the # character is a fragment url. The portion on the right of the # (that you want to access) is a fragment identifier i.e. a location within the page.
The browsers do not implement document.referrer to pass this identifier, this is in line with HTTP_REFERRER header passed to web pages.
If both of your iframes are from same domain i.e you are able to access parent.location from the child, then you can get the hash portion using **parent.location.hash**.
Hard luck otherwise