# JS code to get previous page url including the data after #

Tags: javascript, url

I need url data of the previous page including the data after #

example: sample.com#test

I used document.referrer but I am getting only sample.com

I need the complete url like sample.com#test.

Comment: Is for to go back to the previous page?

Comment: No, I need the previous page complete url including the data after #

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it. The hash code isn't sent to the next page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to get documents referrer with hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874755/javascript-how-to-get-documents-referrer-with-hash)